# Font "DINPro-Regular" not showing in newsletter

Tags: html, css, webfonts, newsletter

I use a custom font for a newsletter. I have imported "DINPro-Regular" font which works in chrome web browser, but doesn't work in outlook or gmail newsletter. I tried 'Roboto' and it is showing up in outlook as well as gmail. can someone point out what could be causing this issue?

any help would be much appreciated.

```
<style type="text/css">

    @import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto&display=swap');


    @font-face {
        font-family: "DINPro-Regular";
        src: url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/c9c60c88cb732119e5a9457f2d9cdc53.eot"); /* IE9*/
        src: url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/c9c60c88cb732119e5a9457f2d9cdc53.eot?#iefix") format("embedded-opentype"), /* IE6-IE8 */
        url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/c9c60c88cb732119e5a9457f2d9cdc53.woff2") format("woff2"), /* chrome firefox */
        url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/c9c60c88cb732119e5a9457f2d9cdc53.woff") format("woff"), /* chrome firefox */
        url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/c9c60c88cb732119e5a9457f2d9cdc53.ttf") format("truetype"), /* chrome firefox opera Safari, Android, iOS 4.2+*/
        url("https://db.onlinewebfonts.com/t/c9c60c88cb732119e5a9457f2d9cdc53.svg#DINPro-Regular") format("svg"); /* iOS 4.1- */
    }

body { font-family: 'DINPro-Regular', 'Trebuchet MS'; }

    a {
        text-decoration: none;
    }

</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

well, custom fonts aren't supported in most popular email clients. Email clients ripoff most of your css stuff.

add image + alt text or fallback to web safe fonts like :

- Arial (sans-serif)
- Verdana (sans-serif)
- Helvetica (sans-serif)
- Times New Roman (serif)
- Courier New (monospace)

more font : https://www.cssfontstack.com/

you can check for font-face support in email :  https://www.caniemail.com/features/css-at-font-face/

Comment: It doesn't work in both gmail or outlook not only one client. I am wondering if problem is with this server links or in all cases it will not work. Fonts from "googleapis" seem to be working. But this specific font is not available there.